# ticker text null in NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, notifications

I am writing NotificationListenerService , 
where I want to get the details of notification sent to status bar.

But only thing we get is Ticket text , which is null in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

Correct, ticker text is **not** a required field when building a notification. In fact, the only [required notification contents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Required) are:

- A small icon - returned by `icon`
- A title - returned by [extras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#extras).getCharSequence([Notification.EXTRA_TITLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#EXTRA_TITLE))
- Detail text - returned by [extras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#extras).getCharSequence([Notification.EXTRA_TEXT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#EXTRA_TEXT))

Unfortunately, the `extras` bundle is only available on Android 4.4 (KitKat) devices - previous versions do not have any easy access to this data - you only have access to the `RemoteViews` which you'd need to inflate and parse manually (definitely not recommended).

Comment: I am using Android 4.3

Comment: how can you get the extras in previous versions ? or how you get the info from the remote views ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ticker text is optional, and may be null in some cases.

You haven't posted any code, but are you using the `onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification)` method from `NotificationListenerService`? That was implemented in API 18 (Android 4.3), so it should work for you. [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#onNotificationPosted%28android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification%29) states that the full `Notification` object should be returned, which should give you more than just the ticker text.